# function domain and range

Tags: functions

> Let *h(x) = f(g(x))*, where *f* and *g* are functions. Suppose every value in the range of *g* is in the domain of *f*. Must the domain of *h* be the same as the domain of *g*?

Apparently the answer is Yes, but I'm not sure I understand why. Shouldn't it be *g(x)* instead, which is the range of *g*, not the domain of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a con of a question, since the domain is part of the definition of a function.

In order for this to be defined, you need some spaces (not necessarily the same), $X,Y,Z$ where $g$ maps from $X$ to $Y$ and $f$ maps from $Y$ to $Z$. Then, the composition $h = f \circ g$ is definable as a map from $X$ to $Z$. You can think of it as taking a value $x$ from $X$, pushing it to something in $Y$, which is $g(x)$ and then pushing that value to something in $Z$ which is $f(g(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: visualize as $\;h = f \circ g\;$ where:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \text{domain of} \;g @>g>> \text{range of} \;g \subseteq \text{domain of} \;f @>f>> \text{codomain of} \;f\\
\end{CD}
$$